# Webapp to easily sell a file online (for tiny niche markets not worth of hosting an eshop)

Tags: gratis, web-apps

Let's say I spend a week creating a data file in order to sell it to a very small niche market (maybe 100 buyers worldwide).

Is there an online platform where people could download the file in exchange for money, which I would get minus a margin/fee?

Requirements:

- Online.
- Supports any kind of file, even binary presumably-opaque data.
- Sharable landing page for my file with at least a bit of metadata.
- Users can download updates for free after they have paid once.
- Users can pay with mainstream credit cards, the more payment options the better.
- No set up fee.

*Note: I am not worried about piracy because it is such a niche market, and because of updates.*

Comment: Very nice question, since setting-up a small e-shop in some Cms only for this small market it's an overkill

Comment: Payment by credit-card usually requires you to have a merchant status bank account, and for that to support cardholder-not-present transactions. Is that something you are pursuing or have considered? You can most likely find third-party payment integrators that isolate you from that, but having or not having the merchant status changes your question.

Comment: eBay may be suitable for taking payment? http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/downloadable.html - it doesn't match your other hosting/update requirements directly though, you would need a way to provide necessary download links.

Comment: @NeilSlater: I did not know eBay could be used for this! Could you please post as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eBay may be suitable for your project, given the small market. The eBay site [has a policy for downloadable content](http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/downloadable.html) This doesn't address your other hosting requirements directly, you would need to generate and email out links for each order on your own site. If you keep each link active and allow latest version to be downloaded then that would deal with updates.

Links could be a simple as a long random number that you generate for each confirmed order. This makes it secure against simple guessing by someone who has not ordered, but does not protect you from people sharing links or just directly sharing the content.

Answer (score 2):

I've only had experience with it in making a purchase (not selling), but [Gumroad](http://gumroad.com) might be a good option. It allows selling any type of digital product, and [also supports updating](http://blog.gumroad.com/post/42440012894/updating-a-file). Though you said piracy isn't a concern, it does support PDF stamping to help to mitigate piracy of PDFs (if that's the format of file you happen to be selling).

Going through your requirements one-by-one:

- Online. **Yes.**
- Supports any kind of file, even binary presumably-opaque
  data. **Yes.**
- Sharable landing page for my file with at least a bit of
  metadata. **Yes.**
- Users can download updates for free after they have paid
  once. **Yes.**
- Users can pay with mainstream credit cards, the more payment
  options the better. **Yes.**
- No set up fee. **Yes.**