# CMS or similar Framework that has solved my problem?

Tags: cms, framework

Here is my problem -- I sure hope it's old hat the bulk of which I don't need to build entirely on my own.

The domain is that of private school Judaic teachers who do not in the aggregate constitute an effective market for education tool/material makers, and therefore pretty much spend much time creating and recreating wheels, of varying quality, each scratching itches particular to their particular domain.

So I need to make a website (or even a client/server app) where 1. users can browse, download and submit materials and tools in various formats (let's start off with PDF and Powerpoint slides) -- this itself is not novel nor very effective (it's been done in the past...and the quality of the materials is wanting more often than not...) the novelty and difficulty is in the details...

Detail 1. I need to build an attending mechanism whereby users can 1. request materials to be made for payment and along the same lines a mechanism whereby users can submit materials for sale. And of course a payment processing mechanism (there are I know plenty of 3rd party options, thank G-d).

Detail 2. I need to make sure (within reason) that the materials uploaded to the server are the materials that in the end make it to the end user, i.e. not infected with bad stuff, infecting all the users. I could vet users--there is no requirement for 'open' access--and could implement some sort of signing/checksum verification

No I am not asking for development steps...I am asking if what I am describing is the problem domain addressed by a particular genre of app or framework. I am asking for guidance about what to research.

I would very much prefer work within a Python or Java EE context.

Comment: If I understand well, this question is a bit like http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3112 but private to a particular community? Do you need to host it yourself, or is an online solution OK?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul It is similar to that question, which I actually upvoted yesterday, but different in that this would be as much a repository for 'donated' materials or house purchased materials as it would be a pure platform for a transaction. So, yeah, it would relate to the particular community, I doubt an online solution would offer enough control over or even insight into the back-end or extensibility to meet the need. However  a pre-packaged self host-able solution like, say, youtrack would be perfect if it suited the purpose and was reasonably transparent and extensibile.

Comment: `'donated' materials or house purchased materials` ← only digital stuff? Or also physical stuff?

Comment: Only digital materials.

Comment: I use my own product for a similar thing, but not including payments (all free content). You might wish to take a look at it, it even includes a Judaica section for books. But if you need an interface to have users easily add items, that's not included. Being fully OpenSource, you can of course add this yourself. Find it here: [The Book Server in action](http://ebooks.qumran.org/) / [the code](http://projects.izzysoft.de/trac/minicalope). If this would be an acceptable answer, let me know and I make it one.